# How to cross compile libcollections for ARM?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile libcollections library for ARM architecture. After running the command `./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi`, it fails with the error `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`.

Inside the config.log file, I found that this is due to `as: unrecognized option '-meabi=5'`.

What does this line mean and how do I resolve this issue?

The library is found here: https://bitbucket.org/manvscode/libcollections

Comment: Tip: Google the error message verbatim (in quotes) [*"as: unrecognized option '-meabi=5'"*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=as%3A+unrecognized+option+%27-meabi%3D5%27&meta=&gfe_rd=ssl&ei=cx86V4W0JMjDaKb-k7gF#hl=en&q=%22as:+unrecognized+option+%27-meabi%3D5%27%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-meabi=5` is an [ARM specific GNU assembler command line option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Options.html#ARM-Options) to specify the EABI version to be used, where valid values are 4, 5 and gnu.

You should ensure that you have installed an appropriate build of binutils for ARM, as per the solution [here](https://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/4455/unrecognized-option-meabi-5-or-unrecognized-option-mcpu-cortex-m3).

Comment: It turns out my ARM compiler installation is incomplete. Thanks.